# Drop Database Schema and all tables in OracleXE

Tags: database, schema, sqlplus, oracle-xe

I'm very confused, since I've tried a lot of tuts online, but still there are errors or inconsistencies in the schema when i try to drop a User\Database through SqlPlus.

Every time I need to relaunch, for example, a dll through script, I need a blank schema\user, so I'm forced to reinstall OracleXE to obtain this!

Can anybody share some light here?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Drop user user_name cascade;
```

use the above command while logging in sys as sysadmin, and this will delete the schema/user name which deletes all the tables

Comment: Yes,,,already tested. tables are still there...now I'm on a different machine, I'll try again now and report to u...

Comment: Well...now it seems to work. Fine, maybe was a corrupted instance...thanks for your support!